# How to handle sender tag in Alert View

Tags: ios5, uialertview

I am very new to iOS development. I have the following method done by another developer

```
-(IBAction)btnDelete:(UIButton *)sender
{
    indexOfBlockedFriend=sender.tag-50;
    [self deleteFriend];
}
```

I want to show an alert view before the delete action is performed. How do I do that.

Answer (score 2):

To handle `AlertView` button click, you have to conform to `UIAlertViewDelegate` protocol.
in your.h

```
@interface YourViewController:UIViewController<UIAlertViewDelegate>{
  .......
  .......
}
```

Then implement UIAlertViewDelegate protocol methods,
in your.m

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView 
                   clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex{
    if (buttonIndex == 0){
      //cancel clicked ...do your action
    }else if (buttonIndex == 1){
      //reset clicked
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

With the UIAlertView class

```
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Hello World" message:@"Hello" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:nil];
[alert show];
```

If you want to have more than one option you will need to become the delegate for the alert to get a callback for which button was touched. Delegation is a concept of Object Oriented Programming (OOP) that you will have to become familiar with.

EDIT:

You may be interested in block-based UIAlertViews. The one that I use in a lot of projects is called UIAlertView+MKBlockAdditions. It contains easy methods for handling all the alert delegate logic in a block handled by the alert.

Comment: The problem isn't showing the alert view, but handling the delete action on the press of the "OK" button of the Alert View. When I call the alert view method, I pass the control to the alert view method. How do I then invoke the same action of deleting the user from the list view i.e.   indexOfBlockedFriend=sender.tag-50;
    [self deleteFriend];

Comment: @Quality Coder answered that. You must become the delegate of the alert, and implement the clickedButtonAtIndex: method. The alertView sends the button index as a parameter to the method, so you can query for buttonIndex != 0 (which is the cancel index), and run your deletion code there.